# Не получается сделать правильный массив целых чисел и чисел с десятичными дробями

Tags: php, html, jquery, регулярные-выражения

Всем привет. Вопрос по регулярным выражениям - есть строка

```
<span class="quantity">1 × <span class="amount">360.000&nbsp;руб.</span></span>
```

Я пробую из нее вытащить массив:

```
var quantity = $(".quantity").text().match(/\d+\.\d+/g)
```

получаю массив ["360.000"]
делаю вот так

```
var quantity = $(".quantity").text().match(/\d+/g)
match(/\d+/g)
```

Я получаю: `["1", "360", "000"]`

Мне нужно получить `["1", "360.000"]`.

Что я делаю не правильно?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Необходимо поправить выражение вот так:

```
var quantity = $(".quantity").text().match(/\d+(?:\.\d+)?/g)
```

Объяснение:

- `\d+` - 1 или более цифр
- `(?:\.\d+)?` - Необязательная группа, которая находит

  - `\.` - точку
  - `\d+` - 1 или более цифр

Если необходимо, можно добавить знаки `+` или `-`, но мне кажется, что это в Вашем случае не нужно.

А вот как это выражение выглядит на рисунке:

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Демо на Debuggex](https://www.debuggex.com/r/nmYBQLq_tRLUR0xW)

В сети есть множество сервисов для расшифровки и отладки регулярных выражений, например вышеупомянутый [Debuggex](http://www.debuggex.com) и [Regex101](https://regex101.com/).

Пример кода:

```js
var quantity = $(".quantity").text().match(/\d+(?:\.\d+)?/g)
console.log(quantity);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="quantity">1 × 360.000 руб.</div>
```

Результат:

```
["1", "360.000"]
```

Comment: ага, Вы правы, удалил свой ответ и дописал в ваш ссылку на regex101

Comment: @stribizhev все бы хорошо, но выводит дубоикаты
["1", "360.000", "1", "360.000", "1", "360.000"]

Comment: @Вася: а как выглядит входная строка? Если `1 × 360.000 руб.`, то не должно быть проблем.

Comment: все, ок - это у меня инфа дублировалась - вопрос снят